# Where is this Laravel 5.1 queue listener coming from?

Tags: laravel

Whenever I check for running processes, I notice this process running:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.24/bin/php artisan queue:work --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=local
```

I notice it gets a new process id every few seconds. In my /app/Console/Kernel.php file I have nothing in the schedule() command. Furthermore, there is nothing in my crontab. What is causing this listener process to run and restart and run as if controlled by a cron job?